# Align bootstrap columns in left-right-left order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid-layout

I dont know how to start this question, I want make this grid with bootstrap but I cant do the following:

*Dekstop mode*

```
+-----------------+------------------------------+
|    content1     |                              |
|                 |           content2           |
+-----------------+                              |
|                 |                              |
|    content3     +------------------------------+
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

*Mobile mode*

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|                  content1                      |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                  content2                      |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                  content3                      |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Does somebody know the code to make?

Comment: The best way is to show what code you have tried with so far.

Comment: This is achievable in CSS but please post some sample markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The middle div needs to be floated right. The `pull-right` class can do just that. However, on smaller screens, the float interferes with non-floated elements on smaller screens. Therefore the `col-xs-12` class is required.

```css
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Three columns with a right float</h1>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 bg-primary">
      <h2>Content 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed dignissim neque.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 pull-right bg-success">
      <h2>Content 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed dignissim neque. Donec fringilla enim sit amet felis aliquam, at varius nisi viverra. Proin ante diam, fermentum non elit vitae, pulvinar tristique dui. Fusce malesuada libero
        sit amet est molestie, sit amet pharetra nisi mattis.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 bg-info">
      <h2>Content 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed dignissim neque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See revised answer; the same principles apply, however, this time with bootstrap classes.